# Compile error when including OpenSSL headers in a new swift project

Tags: objective-c, swift, openssl, include

I started a new swift project and added files from objc project.
I got compiling error at OpenSSL include file. See image below.

[image: Compiling error]

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm guessing nearly no one can read the small text in the picture. You should post the text of the error so it can be read by current visitors and indexed for future visitors.

Comment: You can click on the picture

Answer (score 0):

Solved: Updating the project's Header Search Path. (At build settings)